# ActionLink shows wrong url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have some pre-defined URLs in routing table actually directing to same controller and action, but different language. For example

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            "Contact", // Route name
            "contact", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Contact", lang="en" } // Parameter defaults
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
            "Contact2", // Route name
            "iletisim", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Contact", lang="tr" } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

When i use `Html.ActionLink` in View and run application, URL shows the first route, for example:

```
@Html.ActionLink(Resources.Contact, "Contact", "Home")
```

When current language is `tr` when page rendered URL is : `/contact` which should be `/iletisim` instead.

When i change the order of route mappings then `en` language pages shows wrong URL.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When matching a route from `ActionLink`, you must take all of the parameters that the route generates into consideration. The framework will always return the first match for the supplied route values.

In your case, you are supplying the route values:

```
controller = "Home"
action = "Contact"
```

Which given the lack of other information will match your `Contact` route (the first route with `controller = "Home", action = "Contact"`).

If you want to match a specific route, then you need to pass the `lang` route value as well.

```
@Html.ActionLink(Resources.Contact, "Contact", "Home", new { lang = "tr" }, null)
```

That will match the `Contact2` route.

Alternatively, you can put the `lang` into the URL of the page, which would ensure that it is part of the current request as shown in [ASP.NET MVC 5 culture in route and url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32839796/181087)
. Then MVC will automatically supply this value to all of your `ActionLinks` and other `UrlHelper` based methods.

Comment: thank you, i get it. But now it adds querystring "?lang=tr" to the end of url which i don't want it.